# Creating a class dynamically

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic, attributes

I'm trying to create a new class, without knowing the name of the class until it's supposed to be created.

Something like this;

```
    variable = "ValidClassName"
    
        class variable
    
        end

Test = ValidClassName.new
```

If possible, i'd also appreciate som hints on how to dynamically add attributes (and methods) to this new class.

I'll be retreiving 'settings' for the class, and they will look something like this:

```
title :Person
attribute :name, String
attribute :age, Fixnum
```

But should not be designed to accept only that explicit file, the attributes might differ in number end type.

Which in the end will generate a class that should look something like:

```
class Person
   def initialize(name, age)
 
       @name_out = name
       @age_out = age
   end
   
end
```

Help?

Comment: you're wanting to just create the source code for a class? or are you wanting to generate the source and tell ruby to compile/load the class at runtime?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem are you solving? How do you plan on using these dynamically created classes?

Comment: My class is supposed to act as a 'frame', once created ill use to instantiate objetcs (as long as they meet the demands, set by the class) from an yaml-file.

The YAML hold a bunch of "people", and some of them have attributes that match the requirements.

Comment: I really should come around to finish that course. Any day now..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A class gains its name when it is assigned to a constant. So It's easy to do in a generic fashion with `const_set`.

For example, let's say you want to use `Struct` to build a class with some attributes, you can:

```
name = "Person"
attributes = [:name, :age]

klass = Object.const_set name, Struct.new(*attributes)
# Now use klass or Person or const_get(name) to refer to your class:
Person.new("John Doe", 42) # => #<struct Person name="John Doe", age=42>
```

To inherit from another class, replace the `Struct.new` by `Class.new(MyBaseClass)`, say:

```
class MyBaseClass; end

klass = Class.new(MyBaseClass) do
  ATTRIBUTES = attributes
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
  def initialize(*args)
    raise ArgumentError, "Too many arguments" if args.size > ATTRIBUTES.size
    ATTRIBUTES.zip(args) do |attr, val|
      send "#{attr}=", val
    end
  end
end
Object.const_set name, klass
Person.new("John Doe", 42) # => #<Person:0x007f934a975830 @name="John Doe", @age=42>
```

Comment: I'm getting and error while declaring the klass, the name should be a constant, so I capitalized klass to Klass in 2, 3 lines and now it's working.

Answer (score 13):

Your code would look something akin to this:

```
variable = "SomeClassName"
klass = Class.new(ParentClass)
# ...maybe evaluate some code in the context of the new, anonymous class
klass.class_eval {  }
# ...or define some methods
klass.send(:title, :Person)
klass.send(:attribute, :name, String)
# Finally, name that class!
ParentClass.send(:const_set, variable, klass)
```

...or you could just use eval:

```
eval <<DYNAMIC
  class #{name}
    title :Person
    attribute :name, String
    # ...or substitute other stuff in here.
  end
DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm really out of my depth here. Could you please try to explain it as if i was three years old..? :p

Comment: I am not sure this gets that much easier.  The second case is probably easier to understand: `eval` takes a string, and evaluates it *at the time of the call* as if it is Ruby code.  So, you create a string with the source code for your dynamic class at runtime, then evaluate it.  The first case creates a new class object, does things to it to create the desired methods, etc, and then gives it a name - which in Ruby is the same as assigning the class object to a constant.